# Opening only particular link in web browser in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am working on a winforms in c# where in my application user will provide a links that will be saved in my database and when the user want to open that link, it will open in web browser.
Now, when I do so, the link successfully open in web browser but the user can also open any other videos (if the link is of YouTube). But, I want that when web browser open then it only show that particular link and user can't play other videos on YouTube.
How can I do so??

Comment: What WebBrowser are you referring to? You tagged this question `webbrowser-control`, which doesn't open any new tab on its own.

Comment: @Jimi I edited the question, sorry I don't know why I misunderstood that others webpages can also open but what I have problem is with YouTube that I want to display only that video which will be in link

Comment: Are you using a **WebBrowser Control** or not?

Comment: I have dragged web browser from tool box, i read it some where and that was mentioned under the label of web browser control so i did put it as label.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/webbrowser-control-in-C-Sharp-and-windows-forms/   I used this method

Comment: If you want to prevent the navigation in some situations, subscribe to the `WebBrowser.Navigating` event, check the current URL and call `e.Cancel()` if you don't allow it.